# "Have you had a breakfast" or "did you have a breakfast"?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, sentence-choice

Which one is correct "have you had a breakfast" or "did you have a breakfast"? And should I use the ‘a’ s, is it necessary to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Neither is correct!

The usual question is either:

> Have you had breakfast (yet)?
>   or
>   Did you have breakfast - usually, but not necessarily, followed by a time reference - this morning?

However, one uses the indefinite article before an adjective preceding **breakfast**

> Did you have a good/hearty/substantial breakfast this morning?
>   Have you had a good breakfast in preparation for a hard day's work.